# Display the sorted array in 2 columns

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make it so that my code displays if entered array of numbers can be divided into 2 groups, and if yes then it displays"yes" or if no then"no. The yes or no part works fine, but if the code says yes then I want the code to also display the 2 columns with the numbers, I tried a lot but I just can't figure it out, please help.

```
function helper(&$arr, $n, $start, $lsum, $rsum) {
    if ($start == $n)
        return $lsum == $rsum;

    if ($arr[$start] % 5 == 0)
        $lsum += $arr[$start];
    else if ($arr[$start] % 3 == 0)
        $rsum += $arr[$start];
    else
        return helper($arr, $n, $start + 1, $lsum + $arr[$start], $rsum)
            || helper($arr, $n, $start + 1, $lsum, $rsum + $arr[$start]);

    return helper($arr, $n, $start + 1, $lsum, $rsum);
}

function splitArray($arr, $n) {
    return helper($arr, $n, 0, 0, 0);
}

$arr = array( 7,1, 7,3,4,6);
$n = count($arr);

if (splitArray($arr, $n))
    print("Yes");
     
else
    print("No");
```

Comment: What exactly are you unable to figure out? Nothing in the code you've shared does any displaying. I'd recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it has lots of good pointers for what a question needs to contain. If your problem is displaying, you need to share the revelant code and an explanation of what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you want to split them into two parts
Replace your code at the bottom with...

```
$arr = array( 7,1, 7,3,4,6);
$n = count($arr);

list($group1, $group2) = array_chunk($arr, ceil(count($arr) / 2)); //Split the initial array into 2 if you want 3 just change 2 to 3 and so forth

if (splitArray($arr, $n)){
        echo "Yes";
        print_r($group1);
         print_r($group2); //Each array assigned to new variable
 } else {
         echo "No";
                          }
```